# Method not available in Generic Return Object

Tags: java

I am trying to access the method `GetDatbaseName()`, from the returned object `obj`, but it is returning error that the method is not available.

However, when I Typecast the `obj`, it is working.

```
String name = ((Oracle)obj).GetDatabaseName();
```

How to handle this generic? Like I can't typecast for each return type like `Oracle` and `MongoDB`. Also any better implementation for this?

```
// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Data dt = new Data("Oracle");
    Object obj = dt.GetObject();

    String name = obj.GetDatabaseName();

    System.out.println(name);
  }
}

public class Data
{
    public String _type;

    public Data(String type)
    {
      _type = type;
    }

    public Object GetObject()
    {
      Object obj = null;

      switch(_type)
      {
        case("Oracle"):

        obj = new Oracle("Test");

        break;

        case("MongoDB"):

        obj = new MongoDB("TestCollection");

        break;

      }

      return obj;
    }
}


public class Oracle
{
  public String _databaseName;

  public Oracle(String databaseName)
  {
    _databaseName = databaseName;
  }

  public String GetDatabaseName() { return _databaseName; }
}

public class MongoDB
{
  public String _collectionName;

  public MongoDB(String collectionName)
  {
    _collectionName = collectionName;
  }

  public String GetCollectionName() { return _collectionName; }
}
```

Comment: There is no other way. Perform the type cast when you know the underlying object is an `Oracle`.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know about the return type and how to handle this?

Comment: I creating Subclasses of `Data` like `OracleData` and `MongoDbData` an Option? Having a completly undefined data type as above doesn't seem all that usefull.

Comment: This is just an example, but I have other similar implementation which I cannot change.

Comment: Take care of java naming convention. Method names should Start with lower case caracters

Comment: Use either Generic classes or Interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this, the first is using a generic `class`, while the second is using `interface`, the second approach is better if you know that the classes will have the same methods, while the generic approach is if the classes have different methods

## Generic approach

```
public class DBtest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        DataBase<Oracle> database = new DataBase<>(Oracle.class);

        Oracle oracle = database.getDataBase();

        System.out.println(oracle.getDatabaseName());
    }
}

class DataBase<T>{
    private T database;

    public DataBase(Class<T> classOfT){
        try {
            database = classOfT.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public T getDataBase(){
        return database;
    }
}


class Oracle{
    private String _databaseName;

    public Oracle(){
        _databaseName = "test";
    }

    public String getDatabaseName() { return _databaseName; }
}
```

As you can see, it is not possible to define the name of the database, this would be possible of you write `<T extends Name>` which is an interface which has `getName()` and `setName()` method

## Interface approach

```
public class DBtest{
    // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
    public static void main(String[] args){
        DataBase database = new DataBase(new Oracle("test"));

        DatabaseName databaseName = database.getDataBase();

        System.out.println(databaseName.getName());
    }
}

interface DatabaseName {
    String getName();
}

class DataBase{
    private DatabaseName databaseName;

    public DataBase(DatabaseName databaseName){
        this.databaseName = databaseName;
    }

    public DatabaseName getDataBase(){
        return databaseName;
    }
}


class Oracle implements DatabaseName {
    private String _databaseName;

    public Oracle(String name){
        _databaseName = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return _databaseName;
    }
}

class MongoDB implements DatabaseName {
    private String _databaseName;

    public MongoDB(String name){
        _databaseName = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return _databaseName;
    }
}
```

Obviously `DatabaseName` is a bad name for an interface, but it is the only method which is the same for both classes, so it makes sense to call it that. The great thing about interfaces is that you don't have to give a shit about what `class` is used as long as you know the method names.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is on the following lines:

```
Object obj = dt.GetObject();

String name = obj.GetDatabaseName();
```

As far as those lines are concerned, obj is of type Object, which does not have the invoked method; thus, the issue. This is due to Java being strongly typed.

To go around that, you need a type that has this method, or use reflection. To use a type that has this method, they need to inherit it from a common parent of implement it from a common interface. You can also wrap you objects or a bunch of other alternatives.

In your case, it seems that a common interface is the easiest way to go. In this case, each class should implement this interface and instead of using Object your reference would be of the type of that interface.

```
public Object GetObject()
```

Would become

```
public MyInterface GetObject()
```

and

```
public class Oracle
```

would be

```
public class Oracle implements MyInterface
```

Where MyInterface would declare the method

```
public interface MyInterface {
    String GetDatabaseName();
}
```

Being mindful of Java conventions, methods should start with lowercase

```
public interface MyInterface {
    String getDatabaseName();
}
```

In the case where you cannot change the code in order to implements those methods, you can use "instanceof" to test against the class type.

```
name = (obj instanceof Oracle)?((Oracle)obj).GetDatabaseName():((MongoDB )obj).getCollectionName();
```

Comment: What in case of MongoDB Object, it wont contain the method GetCollectionName(), so I cant use MyInterface in this case and that is my actual problem

Comment: In this case you can use "instance of" to check if it is of that type

Comment: @DON. Yo dont need to care about `getCollectionName` vs `getDatabaseName`. Since you are abstraction client from knowing if it is dealing with relational vs nosql storage you also need not expose the difference between databaseName and collectionName. If you dont like `MyInterface.getDatabaseName` then change it to `MyInterface.getStorageName` and delegate that method to `getDatabaseName` for Oracle implementation or to `getCollectionName` for MongoDB implementation.

Comment: Agreed, you could add the new common method to both classes and to the interface, this method would then call the original.

Comment: Actually I should have asked the question in a different way. My method signatures are different for Oracle and MongoDB and so I cant go with interface. Moreover this is not an actual implementation, I just added some examples

Comment: what about "instanceof" name = (obj instanceof Oracle)?((Oracle)obj).GetDatabaseName():((MongoDB )obj).getCollectionName();

Answer (score 1):

You must have to create an Interface and then with getDatabaseName() method. Then your objects Oracle and MongoDB must implement that interface.
What you are trying to do is something similar to AbstractFactory Pattern. You should google it.

```
public interface MyDbInterface {
    String getDatabaseName();
}
public class HelloWorld {
    // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
    public static void main(String[] ){
        MyDbInterface dt = DataFactory.create("Oracle");
        String name = dt.getDatabaseName();

        System.out.println(name);
    }
}

public final class DataFactory{

    private DataFactory(){
        super();
    }

    public static MyDbInterface create(String type){
        MyDbInterface obj = null;

        switch(type) {
            case("Oracle"):
                obj = new Oracle("Test");
            break;
            case("MongoDB"):
                obj = new MongoDB("TestCollection");
            break;

        }
        return obj;
    }
}


public class Oracle implement MyDbInterface{
    public String databaseName;

    public Oracle(String databaseName){
        databaseName = databaseName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDatabaseName() { 
        return databaseName; 
    }
}

public class MongoDB implement MyDbInterface{
    public String collectionName;

    public MongoDB(String collectionName){
        collectionName = collectionName;
    }

    public String getCollectionName() { 
        return collectionName; 
    }

    @Override
    public String getDatabaseName() { 
        return getCollectionName(); 
    }
}
```

I suposed you come from C#, check java style guide. ;)

Comment: Yes,  I do development in c# and new to Java. MyDbInterface doesn't have signature for getCollectionName??

Answer (score 0):

You should think about the design of your code. You need to use basic OOP principal to solve the problem. There are several ways to solve your problem like using interface/generics etc. Here I am giving one such example.

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Data dt = new Data("Oracle");
        DataBase obj = dt.GetObject();
        String name = obj.getDatabaseName();
        System.out.println("Name : "+name);
    }
}

class Data {
    public String _type;

    public Data(String type) {
        _type = type;
    }

    public DataBase GetObject() {
        DataBase dataBase=null;
        switch (_type) {
        case "Oracle":
            dataBase = new Oracle(); 
            break;
        case "Mongo":
            dataBase = new MongoDb(); 
            break;

        }
        return dataBase;
    }
}

interface DataBase {
    String getDatabaseName();
}

class Oracle implements DataBase {
    public String getDatabaseName() {
        return "Oracle";
    }
}

class MongoDb implements DataBase {
    public String getDatabaseName() {
        return "Mongo";
    }
}
```

Edited:

Here is another way to solve your problem. I believe this approach might solve your problem.

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Data<Oracle> dt = new Data<Oracle>("Oracle");
        Oracle obj = dt.getObject();
        String name = obj.getDatabaseName();
        System.out.println("Name : "+name);
    }
}

class Data<T> {
    public String _type;

    public Data(String type) {
        _type = type;
    }

    public T getObject() {
        Object dataBase=null;
        switch (_type) {
        case "Oracle":
            dataBase = new Oracle(); 
            break;
        case "Mongo":
            dataBase = new MongoDb(); 
            break;

        }
        return (T)dataBase;
    }
}


class Oracle  {
    public String getDatabaseName() {
        return "Oracle";
    }
}

class MongoDb {

}
```

Comment: Again same comment from other answer.. My method signatures will be different and I cant use same interface..